# Probabilities of two correlated random variables and its probable magnitude

Tags: probability, random-variables, correlation, linear-regression

1) Let's say we have a process defined by two random variables **X** and **Y**. Both processes are perfectly correlated +1, the vectors are defined as follow:

```
x =[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
y = [100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900]
```

if one were to calculate the correlation matrix for the above:

```
[1 1]
[1 1]
```

By taking a **linear regression** to see the relationship between **X** and **Y** we get that two processes are correlated and one changes as a function of the other one by a factor (slope M) of **100**.

```
Y = mx + b... 
Y = 100X
```

So one can say that the time series random variable **Y** is a function of random variable **X**.

Therefore, if one needs to describe the above process using probabilities, we can say that random variable Y will vary by 100, 100% of the times (the coefficient of determination on this case happens to be 1).

So here's the fun part...

2) Assume we have two new random variables **X2** and **Y2**, the only things we know about these two random variables is that their correlation coefficient changes through time and can be modeled by:

**C = sin(t)** `where t = seconds.`

Making their correlation matrix look something like:

```
[   1  sin(t)]
[sin(t)   1  ]
```

And their linear relationship is defined by `Y2 = mX2 + b` where **M = 2*sin(t+1)** with a coefficient of determination **R^2 = 1/2*sin(t) + 1/2**

**Given an interval between t=0 and t=30. if we were to do a summation of ALL elements between that interval of X2(t) and Y2(t), what would be the probability that sum(X2) > sum(Y2)**

My approach so far:

```
Given t = 0,30 
Correlation Coefficient: sin(0) = 0, sin(30) = 0.5 (degrees, not radians)
Linear relationship between variables = 2*sin(0+1) = 0.034, 2*sin(30) = 1
R^2 (coefficient of determination) = 1/2*sin(0) + 1/2 = 1/2, 1/2*sin(30) + 1/2 = 0.75
```

- So at point t=0, we know that since there's a 0 correlation (their linear relationship is completely random), so there is **50%** probability that X2(t0) > Y2(t0) or vice versa, and there is a *relatively low probability* of Y2 varying 0.034*X2(t) because the coefficient of determination is 0.5, so it is 50% chance, thus random.
- At point t = 30, we know that since there's a correlation coefficient of 0.5, there's a higher probability of **X2(t30)** and **Y2(30)** INCREASING or DECREASING at the same time with respect to X2(t0) and Y2(t0). The probability is **75%** (because 0.5 is 75% closer to +1 than -1. AND, there is a probability of 87% that the relationship Y2(t) = 1 * X2(t) will hold because of the R^2 coefficient of determination of 0.75 (also **75%** chance).

So the probability at t = 30 of BOTH variables being "BOTH negative **OR** BOTH positive" is 75%, AND the probability of X(30) and Y(30) being EQUAL is 75%. However, I do not know how X2(t0) and Y2(t0) behaves since they are completely random...

I feel there should be an integral somewhere, and calculate the probabilities based on a summation from t=0 to t=30 (with a definite integral). But I am not sure how would this work. Is there any way to model this process mathematically using probabilities?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without the distribution of the variables, it is impossible to infer figures from them, such as $\text{sum}(x2)>\text{sum}(y2)$.

Besides, the indicated sum is actually a (discrete) time sum $\sum_{t_i}^{t_f}P{x2}(x)dx>\sum_{t_i}^{t_f}P{y2}$.

This is explicitly showing the required probabilites of the ocurrence of each given values. Those probabilites need to be computed from the proper densities $p_{x2}(x)$ and $p_{y2}(x)$.

This is a sum rather than an integral, which for a discrete time stochastic process requires to compute the probabilities $P(t)$ for each discrete instant $t$.

If your application support it, you could define a continuous time stochastic process; In that case the probability is actually a differential term, and the sum turns into an integral, though it would require some differential stochastic relation in order to define the process, such as for a Wiener process.